# How to get current and next year in infopath

Tags: date, infopath

I have a field (`todaysDate`) which has the following function: `today()`.

I am displaying that value in a field (textbox) with the function: `substring(todaysDate, 1, 4)` which only gives the year.

I have another field (textbox) which I would like to show the value for the following year.

So for example:

```
`todaysDate`: `2015-10-21`
`textbox`: `2015`
`textbox`: `2016`
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the current year I added a new field:

```
todayYear: substring(now(), 1, 4)
```

To get next year I added another new field:

```
nextYear: sum(todayYear) + 1
```

Answer (score 1):

The second textbox must have the function:

```
val(substring(todaysDate, 1, 4))+1
```

Comment: I get the following error: `'val' is not a valid XSLT or XPath function.`

Comment: maybe you have to include some math library.
I tested it in immediate mode.

Comment: I added the `substring` using the Insert Function... button and added the `val` manually around the function because I didn't see it in a list of function.

Comment: I used Sum() instead and added another variable which handles the addition. Working fine now. Thanks for the pointing me in the right direction.